# RecyclerView content is not displayed when height is 0dp

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-xml

I'm trying to display the contents of an array, which is not empty, in a RecyclerView.
As already mentioned, the array is not empty (have checked).
The ChatAdapter also brings no errors.

As soon as I change the height of the RecyclerView from 0dp to power parent I also see the array's data. However, I would like to adjust the height to the respective content.

How do I proceed?

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/chatRV"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:overScrollMode="never"
app:stackFromEnd="true"
android:padding="@dimen/_20sdp"
android:visibility="gone"
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewBackground"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/viewSupporter"/>
```

My ChatActivity.kt class looks like this:

```java
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    init()
    listenMessages()
   }


   private fun init(){
      preferenceManager = PreferenceManager(applicationContext)
      chatMessages = ArrayList()
      chatAdapter = ChatAdapter(chatMessages,getBitmapFromEncodedString(receiverUser!!.image),preferenceManager.getString(KEY_USER_ID)!!)
      binding.chatRV.adapter = chatAdapter
      db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
  }

      private fun listenMessages(){
      db.collection(KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
          .whereEqualTo(KEY_SENDER_ID,preferenceManager.getString(KEY_USER_ID))
          .whereEqualTo(KEY_RECEIVER_ID,receiverUser!!.id)
          .addSnapshotListener { snapshots, e ->
              if (e != null) {
                  Log.w("listen:error", "listen:error", e)
                  return@addSnapshotListener
              }

              if(snapshots != null)
              {

              val count = snapshots!!.size()
              for (dc in snapshots!!.documentChanges) {
                  when (dc.type) {
                      DocumentChange.Type.ADDED -> {
                          Log.d("new message", "new message: ${dc.document.data}")

                         val newMessage = ChatMessage(dc.document.getString(KEY_SENDER_ID)!!,
                             dc.document.getString(KEY_RECEIVER_ID)!!,
                             dc.document.getString(KEY_MESSAGE)!!,
                             getReadableDateTime(dc.document.getDate(KEY_TIMESTAMP)!!),
                             dc.document.getDate(KEY_TIMESTAMP)!!)

                          chatMessages.add(newMessage)
                      }
                      else -> {}
                  }
              }


              if(count==0)
              {
                  chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
              }
              else{

                  chatAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(chatMessages.size,chatMessages.size)
                  binding.chatRV.smoothScrollToPosition(chatMessages.size-1)
              }

                  binding.chatRV.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                  binding.progressbar.visibility = View.GONE
              }

          }
    }
```

Comment: when you set layout_width/layout_height to 0 inside `ConstraintLayout` with/height is calculate based on constraints ... it is impossible to us(SO users) say why it's not working as you didn't provide enough information ... check your constraint or provide full layout

Comment: Also make sure you have returned right value in getItemCount()

Comment: Doesn't wrap content work?

Comment: No it doesn't..

Comment: Change height to "wrap_content", and mark as recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false)

Answer (score 0):

can you put the hole XML ?
check that this id's also has the right disposition inside your view

app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewBackground"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/viewSupporter"